# Complicated induction proof of helpful inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, induction

I really need help proving the following inequality using induction:
Let $ x\in\left[ 0,1 \right] $. Let's define a sequence $a_{ i }\in\ \{ 0,1,2 \}$ recursive as following: Let $ i\in \mathbb{N} $ and let
$a_{1},...,a_{i}$ be already defined, then define $a_{i+1}$ as:
$$ a_{i+1} = \max(a\in\ \{ 0,1,2 \}: \frac{a}{3^{i+1}} + \sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{a_{j}}{3^{j}} \le x)\ $$

Let's also assume that we don't maximize over the empty set.
Now i want to proove that for all $ i\in \mathbb{N} $: $a_{i+1}$ is defined properly and the following inequality is true:
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{i+1} \frac{a_{j}}{3^{j}} \le x \le (\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{a_{j}}{3^{j}}) + \frac{1}{3^{i}}$$

Does anyone have hints on how to prove it using induction? I don't really get it...
I have problems, especially with the maximum function

I calculated the first few sequence elements: $a_0 = 0$, $a_1=floor(3x)$ except for $x=1$, then $a_1=2$

Answer (score 1):

Assume existence of $a_1,\cdots,a_i$ with the given properties. You know: $$\tag{$\star$}\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{a_j}{3^j}\le x$$And also that $a_i$ is the maximal element of $\{0,1,2\}$ for which this inequality holds. You want to know if there exists any $a_{i+1}\in\{0,1,2\}$ which satisfies the maximum condition. Since $\{0,1,2\}$ is finite, the only obstacle to the existence of the maximum is in the case that the set of $a\in\{0,1,2\}$, $$\frac{a}{3^{i+1}}+\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{a_j}{3^j}\le x$$Is empty. But $a=0$ is always a solution because of the 'inductive hypothesis', the inequality $(\star)$. Thus, $a_{i+1}$ always exists.

You also want to show, rewriting slightly, that: $$\frac{a_{i+1}}{3^{i+1}}+\sum_{j=1}^{i}\frac{a_j}{3_j}\le x\le\frac{a_{i+1}+1}{3^{i+1}}+\sum_{j=1}^i\frac{a_j}{3^j}$$Because $a_{i+1}$ is *maximal*, there is a contradiction there if the inequality is false. Note the left hand inequality always holds by definition of $a_{i+1}$. Have a further think about this!